# ImagickException: Zero size image string passed

Tags: security, pdf, imagemagick, moodle, lms

Following Error occurred. How to resolve this?

> You must set the policy of ImageMagick to allow PDF read. See [override default ImageMagick policy.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703123/override-default-imagemagick-policy-xml)
>
> ImagickException: Zero size image string passed in /home/289812.cloudwaysapps.com/eeyqmgqped/public_html/online/mod/securepdf/view.php:98 Stack trace: #0 /home/289812.cloudwaysapps.com/eeyqmgqped/public_html/online/mod/securepdf/view.php(98): Imagick->readImageBlob() #1 {main}

[image]

Comment: I've never used Cloudways, are you using your own instance and are you able to edit /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml?

Comment: where it is located?

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the policy.xml to include reading permissions like the [install process](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_securepdf) says?

> - Please note that you have to install a PHP module that is not needed by Moodle itself.
> - Install php-imagick module on your system.
> - (debian/ubuntu) apt-get install php-imagick
> - (Redhat/Centos) yum install php-imagick
> - **Configure imagemagick to allow PDF reading, Add `<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PDF">` to the policy at
>   /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml see more details here :
>   [override default ImageMagick policy.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703123/override-default-imagemagick-policy-xml)**
> - **Restart php-fpm or your web server.**
> - cd [moodle]/mod/
> - git clone https://github.com/yedidiaklein/moodle-mod_securepdf.git securepdf
> - Go to your moodle Notification Page and install.

I have never used Cloudways but if it's a managed hosting and you don't have access via shell to the instance you're running on you'll likely have to ask them for a workaround.

Comment: Dear Nelloverflow,

Kindly help me how to install Install php-imagick module on moodle. Already i installed the SecurePDF Module. So Kindly help me to install php-imagick module on moodle.

Thank you,

Comment: php-imagick isn't installed on moodle per se, but on the OS you're running. How did you install moodle exactly?

Comment: Upload a zip file backup & configure the config.php file with database name,username,password & dataroot and then simply run the url doamin.com/online/index.php. i had installed like this only.